# permission denied error while running collectstatic command

Tags: python, django, deployment, digital-ocean

I'm deploying my django project on digitalocean.While it runs correctly in my development machine but on running on server, it's not showing static files.

[image: not showing static files]

my settings for static files is,

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT='/home/gagan_sapora/myprojectdir/saporawebapp/static/'
```

for troubleshooting, i run collectstatic command but it's showing permission denied error.

Edit 1:-
The corresponding error is;-
[Check error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xfqo.png)
I try to change its ownership but it prints

```console
No Such file or directory
```

the file structure of my project is

```
Project
|-Project
|-app
|-static
    |-fonts
    |-images
    |-js
    |-styles
|-manage.py
```

Edit 2:-

my settings.py file is,

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT='../static/'

MEDIA_URL='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After browsing for possible errors and a small discussion with @rsmoji , it's a permission issue as i'm executing command as sudo user, so i need to change permission of the folder using,

```
sudo chmod 777 static
```

It will solve the issue. Hope it would help someone in future

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) 2 separate issues here.

When `DEBUG=True`, Django serves static files itself - it does not go via the collectstatic/STATIC_ROOT path [0].  So the fact that it cannot find smally.jpg suggests that that file is not on the server.  Can you double-check that the file actually exists on your DigitalOcean server?

This permissions error when running `collectstatic` is a different problem, it is likely to do with the owner of the directory specified in `STATIC_ROOT`.  Check which user owns that directory with `ls -l`, and if it is not the user which is running the Django project (usually `www-data`), then you'll need to do `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/static/root`.

[0] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Comment: I doublecheck and yes the file exist on server

Comment: Thanks for adding the extra detail.  I think it is a permissions issue now, so try running `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/gagan_sapora/myprojectdir/saporawebapp/static/`
That command assumes that that the user the django process is running under is www-data, did you follow a tutorial or anything for deploying?

Comment: i already used the command you mentioned but still it's not working.Django is in a virtual environment at level 'myprojectdir/virtualenv'

Comment: now even after collectstaic command , it's not showinh any static files, i'm pasting my settings.py file. please check it